# build windows app using intel xdk (cordova)

Tags: windows, cordova, build, store

I have successfully created an app using Intel XDK. This app is in review on Apple, and deployed to Google Play. However, on trying to deploy to the Microsoft Windows Phone store, I received these errors:

Package acceptance validation error: You don't have permission to submit framework packages at this time. Package XYZ.appx is a framework package.
Package acceptance validation error: The package XYZ.appx specifies an unsupported OsMinVersion in the app manifest: 6.3.0.0.
Package acceptance validation error: OSMinVersion value 6.3.0.0 does not match OSMaxVersionTested value 6.3.1.0 in XYZ.appx.

Does anyone know a solution? My app uses Cordova plug-ins (geolocation, statusbar and globalization).
Do I need to deploy an appx file?